# Embedding code for form in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am using a form generator service that has provided me the following code to embed into my website:

```
<a name="form798688646" id="formAnchor798688646"></a>
<script type="text/javascript"       
src="https://fs28.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?798688646"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
EmbedManager.embed({
   key: "https://fs28.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=m%2FOmK8apOTA80OCs6DyFNWrYe2Y6sJfY&798688646",
   width: "100%",
   mobileResponsive: true
});
</script>
```

I am currently using React JS and am wondering how would I go about adding Embed Code into a component. The first error is thrown by the Key: ... line

```
import React from 'react';
import './Contact.css';


const Contact = () =>  {
    return (

      <div className="contact-container">
        embed code here...
     </div>
    );
};

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

that is just a `<Script>` being run, just make it a function.

```
 MyEmbededCode(){
    EmbedManager.embed({
       key: "https://fs28.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=m%2FOmK8apOTA80OCs6DyFNWrYe2Y6sJfY&798688646",
       width: "100%",
       mobileResponsive: true
    });
 }
```

then you just call that function in your div

```
  <div className="contact-container" onLoad={this.MyEmbededCode()}>
    embed code here...
 </div>
```

I can't remember if it's `onLoad` but you I think you get the jist of things.

Answer (score 0):

AKADER has the right idea but I would use the React lifecycle and just call this function in `ComponentDidMount()` or `ComponentWillMount()`